# How can a noob ask questions about "how to start with this cool stuff"?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, etiquette

I want to express my doubts and disappointments that I get from Stack Exchange. For example, I am a programming beginner using the programming-related sites in the Stack Exchange network, and I believe there are a lot of people out there who face the same problems as me.

Often, when we encounter something awesome, we would like to figure out how to do it, and would love to try it on our own. With all our curiosity, however, we can't find any answers to our questions. **Sometimes, we do not even know what keywords we should use in order to find related answers.**

So here we are, coming to Stack Exchange with our questions which "seem quite stupid", and we get voted down, questions closed, and that's it. The burning enthusiasm goes out.

How can we seek answers to our doubts without getting flamed?

Comment: Do you have a concrete example please? Good (for SO), on-topic questions from noobs (or pros) are always welcome. Can you post a link to a question that got unjustly flamed in your opinion so we can look at it?

Comment: First thing first, I went through your stackoverflow profile and (undeleted) questions and I found it very good and acceptable.

Comment: Drop in chat at the right time and right room. Hopefully, someone may help you.

Comment: @Mat i can't bear to see it and so i deleted it away :/

Comment: @nhahtdh :) i never knew that! Thanks! I should drop by for a chat before jumping into questions

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It seems to be a common misconception that Stack Overflow is intended as the be all, end all of Programmer Information Sharing Resources. This is simply not the case. Its purpose is assembling an archive of solutions to concrete and specific *coding* situations.

Your questions are probably very good questions, and there is no doubt that *everyone*, expert and beginner alike, has the head-scratching moment of "how do I even get started with this?" from time to time. There's *nothing at all* wrong with that, or with having a need for mentoring, tutoring, debugging help, or a desire to share jokes about programmers. But these kinds of posts do not contribute to the core mission here.

In short, I'm afraid that you just need to find another resource for this kind of broad, "where to begin" question. The [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) which were mentioned in comments on your question may be one good resource, although you need a bit of reputation to use them. I hope this doesn't discourage you from using Stack Overflow for its intended purpose. This narrow focus is a feature, not a bug. It's what keeps the site searchable and incredibly useful when you *do* have that well-defined code difficulty.

Comment: This was the gist of my answer. It's conceivable that some 'where do I get started' questions _could_ be narrowly scoped enough to do well on the site, but they're few and far between. We're the place you go once you find the answer to that question, and start talking to the devil that is the details of a specific implementation.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful explanation :) that clears lots of my doubts. I do hope that some day stack exchange will open up a new category for beginners like us ;)

Comment: Please be assured, @yvonnezoe, that any level of experience is welcome on SO, so long as the questions are specific and show some effort. It is not exactly meant to be an expert-only site; it's just meant to be focused on very concrete problems whose solutions will be useful to other programmers. If you're interested, there's a lot of reading material here on Meta about "beginners" and SO: http://www.google.com/search?q=site:meta.stackoverflow.com+beginners+stack+overflow

Comment: @JoshCaswell I see! I hope everyone who faced such problem would see this so that they won't feel upset anymore, just like me :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"how to start with this cool stuff" is a pretty broad question. If someone could write a whole book to answer that question (likely), it's probably [too broad to be a good fit for Stack Exchange](/help/dont-ask). The Stack Exchange format is not really intended to do things like full-blown beginner tutorials. It's much better / naturally suited for depth in specific questions than breadth in broad questions.

What you should do is start by narrowing down on a specific problem you have, and ask a question to address that problem by seeking objective, fact-based answers. If you don't know enough to do that, then it might be a better course of action to look elsewhere. You might find the various tag wikis helpful in finding such other helpful resources.

In terms of the problem of not knowing the technically correct words for things, that's generally fine. Most sites don't really expect that from askers. But we do expect you to fill in that knowledge gap by being descriptive and clear with the words that you do know. Perhaps you can supplement your wording with examples or diagrams.

Remember that one of the primary criteria for the upvote and downvote buttons here is *usefulness*. The fact that you don't know the right words can itself make the post useful, because there's a good chance that other people like you will also not know the right words, but will try to search using the words that you used, and find your question post (and that's a useful thing!).

It's natural to feel discouraged, flustered, and/or frustrated when your post gets downvoted. Keep at it! When you get a downvote, think to yourself "how might I be able to improve this post?". Taking a look at the [Help Center](/help) can help you with that. Upvote weight (10rep) is much more than downvote weight (-2rep).