# Where can i ask a question such as: "would anyone be willing to help mentor a software developer student in the Toronto GTA Area?"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

What would the best section (if there is one) to ask this question?

Comment: [these sites are not a job board](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276250/839601)

Comment: [_"It seems to be a common misconception that Stack Overflow is intended as the be-all, end-all of programmer information sharing..."_](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181995/159251)

Answer (score 6):

There isn't.

That question does not fit the Stack Exchange model. We are here to provide the help directly, not to volunteer to teach people on an individual basis.

Your best bet will be to find a local developer's group (try Facebook or reddit, maybe?) and find out if anyone locally will be interested in helping.

Questions on this network *generally* need to be helpful to a large collection of users "Will you help me/my friend/my cat learn how to code/cook/crochet?" is something that doesn't help anyone outside of your region and anyone who volunteers would likely not be interested in helping everyone who sees the question.

It's just not a good fit for us and there are other resources out there that do this already.